# Statement not accessible

Tags: abap

there is error in line 49 where I wrote `CALL METHOD lclref->lcm .` how can i solve it?

```
REPORT ZPRACTICE_TILL_NOW.

include zlc.
include zinc.

START-OF-SELECTION.
create OBJECT lclref.
CALL METHOD lclref->lcm .
```

first include:

```
class zlcl DEFINITION.
  PUBLIC SECTION.
  METHODS: lcm.
  ENDCLASS.

  CLASS zlcl IMPLEMENTATION.
    method lcm.
    new-LINE.
    WRITE: 'method called '.
    ENDMETHOD.
    ENDCLASS.
```

second include:

```
*&---------------------------------------------------------------------*
*&  Include           ZINC
*&---------------------------------------------------------------------*

    data lclref TYPE REF TO zlcl.
```

Comment: I cannot reproduce your error, there must be something different in your system. Such an error usually occurs when a statement is not inside a procedure or event block, but that's not the case in your example. Please provide a reproducible case.

Answer (score 0):

The error 'Statement not accessible' is because lclref is an object .
To call a method of an object which is referenced to a class ( in this case object -> lclref and class ->zlcl ).

you can directly specify the object and the method .

Hence the corrected code would be : lclref->lcm.

Have fun.

Comment: it is not working I am takeing the new error says that 'statement lclref->lcm is not defined'

Comment: So the problem must be with include zinc. As far as i know. START-OF-SELECTION event must be like this : DATA : lclref TYPE REF TO zlcl. and then CREATE OBJECT lclref right below the reference statement . and then call method. This should work .Because the include was above the start-of-selection event and the statement is not accessible .So you can try removing the include for the reference statement and bring it down to the start-of-selection event .

Answer (score -1):

```
*&---------------------------------------------------------------------*
*&  Include           ZINC
*&---------------------------------------------------------------------*

    data lclref TYPE REF TO zlcl.
```

Are you sure first INCLUDE is zinc

```
class zlcl DEFINITION.
  PUBLIC SECTION.
  METHODS: lcm.
  ENDCLASS.

  CLASS zlcl IMPLEMENTATION.
    method lcm.
    new-LINE.
    WRITE: 'method called '.
    ENDMETHOD.
    ENDCLASS.
```

When I tried with your code I did not getting any error. Please check your INCLUDE which one is the first?

I do not know your SAP version If supports you can use inline declaration. You can see the below example. No need to an extra data declarations

```
DATA(lo_lcl) = new zlcl( ).
lo_lcl->lcm( ).
```